# Passar valor de uma linha na table para inputs na mesma pagina

Tags: php, javascript

tenho uma simples dúvida. Preciso passar os dados de uma linha na minha table para os inputs que estão na mesma pagina.
Segue as telas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem uma solução? Imagino que vou precisar de javascript...ou não?

Comment: pensando de forma rápida, vc iria numerar as <tr id="<?php echo $num ?>" > e pegaria o valor do id via jquery e repassaria as informações dos <td>, existem outras formas também porém essa é mais rápida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma

```js
$(function(){
  $('#Tabela tbody tr').on('click',function(){
   const id = $(this).attr('id');
   const cod = $('#Tabela tbody tr[id='+id+'] td').eq(0).html(),
   nome = $('#Tabela tbody tr[id='+id+'] td').eq(1).html();
   $('#frm #cod').val( cod );$('#frm #nome').val( nome );
  });
 });
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style> tr{ cursor : hand; } </style>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form id="frm" name="frm" method="post">
   <label for="cod">Cód</label><input type="text" id="cod" name="cod" />
   <label for="cod">Nome</label><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
  </form>
  <table id="Tabela" class="table table-sm table-hover table-light table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Cód</td>
     <td>Nome</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
     <td>01</td>
     <td>Fulano de Tal 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
     <td>02</td>
     <td>Fulano de Tal 02</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody> 
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, deu certinho. Valew